# Job re-opened multiple times, Can I do anything?

Tags: interviewing, job-search, career-development

So I applied for a position I am very interested in about 3 months ago.  Job closed and I got an interview.  Interview went well but the hiring manager said there was a candidate that was just a little bit stronger that they were going to offer the position to.  They said the decision wasn't final and that I could still be considered but they didn't want me not to pursue other options while waiting.

Then a month afterward, the position re-opened.  I didn't re-apply as the instructions said not to if I had already applied.  The position closed again.  This time no phone call.  Now about a week ago, the position re-opened again.  This time the close date is set to "Until further notice."

I'm still very interested in the position and I'm wondering what I should do or what I can do.  I still have the contact information from the hiring manager but I don't want to be rude by reaching out to them.  Do I contact the HR department and see what I can do?  Do I just let it go?  I've never been in a situation like this before, so I don't know how to respond to this situation.

Comment: "They said the decision wasn't final and that I could still be considered..." - was this the last thing you heard directly from them. That's what you should go by, not whether a job posting is listed as "opened" or "closed". Look at this site for advice on follow-up and then use those suggestions. Basically you'd just be following up to remind them you're still interested "if the job is still available." Don't mention how you saw that it's listed as opened or closed on the job postings page.

Comment: You didn't get the job!

Answer (score 2):

You are obviously very interested in this position. But the hiring manager might not be. Or they just forgot about you.

Just drop in a mail and check whether they still would like to continue with you or not. If not, move on. Don't seem desperate to them. And I would suggest stop following them so closely if they cannot respect your time and effort after this.
If they do hire you, good luck for your new adventure!

Answer (score 2):

> the hiring manager said there was a candidate that was just a little bit stronger that they were going to offer the position to

It could be that they have as others have said a high turnover of staff,  but I would say from experience they are just fishing (not phishing),  especially if they are advertising directly and not using an agency.   There isn't a specific job,  but if someone exceptional turned up in their net,  they'd find a role for them.

Unfortunately you don't seem to be it.

I think if you look in 6 months it'll still be advertised,  even if the super candidate comes along, I've seen a number of these time wasters in recent years.

Answer (score 1):

Just note that a lot of times job sites have limited time frame positions are open. Say.... 4 weeks or something. The same company posts the same job over and over getting interviews and leads.

It means the position has a very high turn over rate. Matter of fact, I did a search in a area I'm interested in and for 3 years the same place has the same exact job open as I remember last time.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion, based on having been on "the *other* side" of that desk SO many times now, is simply that "dealing with HR *(as a hiring-manager ...)* can be <strike>a little bit</strike> crazy."

For the most part, the HR department is *always* "driving the bus," because their job is to make sure that the company doesn't get sued, or brought into far-worse proceedings by Government goons.  The hiring manager indicates his/her preference, then sends it all back to HR and wonders who *(if anyone)* will eventually show up.

Obviously, your target-company is having considerable difficulty filling this position. Legally speaking, you will need to go through the process of "applying" again. But, if you know the hiring manager's direct phone number, it's okay to call him/her *(even if you just get voice-mail ...)* and re-remind him/her of your sincere interest.

"Then, be patient."  The wheels *must* grind, and they often grind slowly. (And, I assure you, the process is wearisome to *everybody,* with the possible exception of "HR.")